# Ionic 4 observable returning undefined

Tags: observable, ionic4

So I'm using Ionic 4 and have a service interacting with the backend. That's all fine and am able to print the response to the console. Problem is when I try to get the data from my page scripts.

I've scoured through previous questions here but nothing's worked on my end sadly. Anyway here's the code.

My provider, which actually prints the response to the console.

```
getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8090/users")
     .pipe(map((users: any) => {
        console.log("User table: ", users);
      })
    );  
}
```

My page.ts, which prints 
"user names:
undefined"
to the console.

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.feedService.getUsers()
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.users = data; 
      console.log("user names: ");
      console.log(this.users);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the map() operator on your observable you have to return your data or the data is lost.

```
getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8090/users")
        .pipe(map((users: any) => {
            console.log("User table: ", users);
            return users;
            })
        );  
}
```